# Get the file size of the uploaded file in Django app

Tags: python, django, django-file-upload, django-2.2

I would like show in the template the size of a file that the user have uploaded. I've see that the [file object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/files/file/) has the attribute size but, because I'm newbie with Python and the development field, I've been trouble to understand how I can use it.

After some test I've developed this script(*filesize*) to add at the end of the model with which you can upload the file:

```
class FileUpload(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        )
    description = models.TextField(
        max_length=200,
        blank=True,
        )
    file = models.FileField(
        upload_to='blog/%Y/%m/%d'
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def filesize(self):
        x = self.file.size
        y = 512000
        if x < y:
            value = round(x/1000, 2)
            ext = ' kb'
        elif x < y*1000:
            value = round(x/1000000, 2)
            ext = ' Mb'
        else:
            value = round(x/1000000000, 2)
            ext = ' Gb'
        return str(value)+ext
```

Is simple now to call the size of the file.

[image]

I share this because I hope that is usefull for someone. What I ask is this: there is a better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve this by using this custom template tag: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1866/

Use it then like this in your template:

```
{% load sizify  %}

{{ yourFile.size|sizify }}
```

The file size will then be shown in a human readable format (kb, Mb, Gb)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the os module of python to get the size of the uploaded file like `os.path.getsize('Your file path')`

Comment: It is possible to show the size based on kb, Mb, Gb?

Answer (score 1):

I needed something like this and have already started creating a custom template tag. But then after some more googling, I found out that django has builtins - `{{ value|filesizeformat }}`

More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#filesizeformat